# Generic class with explicitly typed constructor

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible to write generic class with one constructor which explicitly defines type of its class?

Here is my attempt to do that:

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ComponentWrapper<T extends JComponent> {

    private T component;

    public ComponentWrapper(String title) {
        this(new JLabel(title));  // <-- compilation error
    }

    public ComponentWrapper(T component) {
        this.component = component;
    }

    public T getComponent() {
        return component;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JButton button = new ComponentWrapper<JButton>(new JButton()).getComponent();
        // now I would like to getComponent without need to cast it to JLabel explicitly
        JLabel label = new ComponentWrapper<JLabel>("title").getComponent();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current code can easily lead to invalid states (e.g. `ComponentWrapper<SomeComponentThatIsNotAJLabel>` that wraps a `JLabel`), and that's likely why the compiler stops you there. You should use a static method instead in this case:

```
public static ComponentWrapper<JLabel> wrapLabel(final String title) {
    return new ComponentWrapper<JLabel>(new JLabel(title));
}
```

Which would be much safer in many ways.

Answer (score 5):

You could cast it:

```
public ComponentWrapper(String title) {
    this((T) new JLabel(title));
}
```

This is due to the Generic information, that could not be used for some instances. For example:

```
new ComponentWrapper() // has 2 constructors (one with String and one with Object since Generics are not definied).
```

The class itself cannot predict such use, in this case the worst case (no Generic info) is considered.

Comment: Thanks. I modified my question to better explain my intention. What I would like to do is `JLabel label = new ComponentWrapper("text").getComponent()`.

Comment: This is terribly unsafe, though. What if I do `new ComponentWrapper<JButton>("SomeString");`? I guess best case one will end up with `ClassCastException`s all over the place...

Comment: `new ComponentWrapper<JButton>("SomeString")` could be a compilation error. No `ClassCastException`s in runtime.

Comment: @miso: this is what you'd like to happen, but is not what the compiler would do.

Comment: I am just wondering why such thing is not allowed, because if you write the constructor I suggest in my question then the compiler has all information to check type safety in compile time.

Comment: And how would it be calculated in raw-type use?